# Escaping a colon in a branch name

Tags: mercurial

I named a hg flow hotfix like bug1234:somthing, and now I can not finish the hotfix I always get:

```
hg: parse error at 6: syntax error
```

Is there a way to escape the colon in the branchname, so I can finish my hotfix?

I'm using:
Ubuntu 11.04
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.8.4)
[HG Flow](https://bitbucket.org/yinwm/hgflow/wiki/Home)

started the hotfix with command:

```
$>hg flow hotfix start bug110711:Billing
```

after coding (bugfix) I tried:

```
$>hg flow hotfix finish bug110711:Billing
hg: parse error at 6: syntax error
```

Comment: please add the exact command you are trying and which platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message of `hg tag` is more clear than the one of `hg flow`:

```
$ hg tag "bug1234:so"
abort: ':' cannot be used in a tag name
```

Comment: actually from the glance I took at the code, the error is coming from trying update to `hotfix/bug110711:Billing`

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. The hg operation I ran was different though, I tried to update to a branch with a colon in the name. The solution was to quote the command twice. So your command will look like this:

```
hg update -r '"My branch with a : character"'
```

The idea is that the outer quotes (') are for the shell and the inner ones (") are for the revset parser.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the special word with "" and entire parameter in ''

e.g

```
hg log -r '::"first"'
```